# Sum a mismatch in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have two columns of £'s values.
Where there is a match or a mismatch I'm trying to SUM them.

I have the £'s values and I have a formula to highlight a match or a mismatch.

I want to be able to SUM any figure in Cost B that mismatches Cost A
If there is a match I also want to SUM that.

I've searched for hours but cannot get anything that worked for me.

[image: Example Cells]

Comment: `=SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,"Match")` and `SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,"Mismatch")`?

Comment: Perfect. I I think the second one will do. Thank you.